# How to create accesslog in OpenLDAP with name "{2}accesslog"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to setup OpenLdap on ubuntu.

The following command is trying to add the accesslog database:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f test.ldif
```

When the name is "`{2}mdb`", the result is success:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart
```

Here is the result:

```
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDatabase: {2}mdb
```

But when the name is "`{2}accesslog`", the result is failed:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}accesslog,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}accesslog
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart

adding new entry "olcDatabase={2}accesslog,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcDatabase> failed init
```

Here is the result:

```
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
```

There is already a database called "`{1}mdb`".
Is it possible for changing the accesslog database name to "`{2}accesslog`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are trying to use LDAP for something it is not intended to. Creating a new database is needed only if you want to create separate DITs, i.e. separate trees with distinct roots.

The "mdb" part in `{1}mdb` is not the *name* of the database, but its *type*. Therefore, it is not a free-form entry, as you need to specify a type of the database the server supports ("mdb" is a safe bet here).